# How to implement search and sort inside a document key in mongodb with php?

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting, search

I have a mobgo document with below structure. I need to perform search and sort inside the "sort_this" and return sorted "sort_this" only. Is that possible using any aggregate function or what is the best method to do this?

```
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "sort_this" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 60
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 50
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 70
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 35
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

If I search for type="homework" and wants to sort results by score in ascending order, expected output is

```
[{
    "type": "homework",
    "score": 35
},
{
    "type": "homework",
    "score": 70
}]
```

Comment: Take a look at $unwind (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Comment: What is your php mongo driver version and can you add an example with the expected output json ?

Comment: My mongodb version 3.2.4 and php extension version is 1.1.5. Expected output is added to the question.